# Reactjs. How to hide results on button and Page Click

Tags: reactjs

**Reactjs.** How to hide results on button and Page Click

I know this question may sound elementary but am just desperate. The following **Reactjs** code displays users record.

This is what I want to achieve.

how to use reactjs to hide results when:

1.) user clicks anywhere on the page.

2.) when a User a Hide button.

Can someone help me with that. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>



<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label id="rootsearch"></label>

    <script type="text/babel">

class NameForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = { data : []}

  }

componentDidMount() {

 this.setState({
           data: [{"id":"1","firstName":"john ","lastName":"Markatti"},
{"id":"2","firstName":"luke","lastName":"henry"}]
        });

}


render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <h2>
How to Hide Result when a user clicks on the Page or on the Hide button
           </h2>



<ul>

<button className="btn btn-primary">Hide Result</button><br />

            {this.state.data.map((person, i) => (

              <li key={i}>
                {person.lastName} - {person.firstName} 
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>

      </span>
   );    
}

}


ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('rootsearch')
);


 </script>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

**An Updates**

For hiding results when a user clicks on a button I have tried the code below
but gets error unexpected token

```
getInitialState: function() {
        return { data: false };
    },

    onClick: function() {
        this.setState({ data: true });
    },

In the render method I have this

<button  onClick={this.onClick}>Hide Result</button><br />
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Hi Sir FrankerZ I have updated my post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to resolve the problem of hiding and showing result. In state within the constructor, 
I set showing variable to true as per code below

```
this.state = { data : [],  showing: true }.
```

Within Render function, I set this showing variable to State.

```
 const { showing } = this.state;
```

Within the return method, I implement hide and show result button as per code below

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({ showing: !showing })}>Hide</button>
```

Finally, I attach the showing variable to map method to hide and show results respectively

```
{showing && this.state.data.map((person, i) => (

              <li key={i}>
                {person.lastName} - {person.firstName} 
              </li>
            ))}
```